# Refresh activity in List-View in Tab (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-activity, refresh

I have a listview in a Tab in a Tab Activity. Lets say that the Activity's name is "Main". I want it so when I press on an item in the listview (which is in a tab, which is in an activity), it refreshes "Main" (The Overall Activity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **onItemClickListener()** for your listview as shown below.

In following example, MainActivity will restart when "Item 1" is clicked.

```js
ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.list_view);
List<String> mList= Arrays.asList("Item 1","Item 2","Item 3");
listView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item_layout,mList));

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Restart activity when Item 1 gets clicked
                if("Item 1".equals(parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString())){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Example: ListViewAdapter.class**

```js
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private List<String>  mList;

    public ListViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<String> list) {
        super(context, resource, list);
        this.mList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout,parent,false);
        }

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item)).setText(getItem(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Considering you are using a FragmentPagerAdapter in your tabbed activity,
you can put the code for the ListView in **onCreateView()** of the corresponding fragment instance,

```js
   @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            ListView listView=rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            List<String> mList= Arrays.asList("Item 1","Item 2","Item 3");
            listView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(rootView.getContext(),R.layout.list_item_layout,mList));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //Restart activity when Item 1 gets clicked
                    if("Item 1".equals(parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString())){
                        if(getActivity()!=null){
                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class));
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```